# How do I configure IntelliJ Run/Debug to execute only the current *.spec.ts file for ng test?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, configuration, angular-test

I am attempting to execute the Angular Test against a single spec.ts file on my CentOS box.

I can use the command line from the OS terminal or within IntelliJ Terminal

```
*ng test --include="somefile.spec.ts"*
```

and the Angular Karma Test will run just that specific file.

However,  I cannot seem to find a way to properly setup the Run/Debug Configuration to allow me to run at just the click of a button the current spec.ts file that I am on.

Here is an image of what I currently have.
**Note: test_file just calls ng test**
[image: Note: test_file just calls ng test]

Would really appreciate some guidance on how to configure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need using `-- --` syntax to pass arguments to a tool run with NPM script, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#description. So I'd suggest changing the **Arguments:** to `-- --include $FileName$`

[image]